# Multiple inheritance with arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, multiple-inheritance

I have been reading quite a bit about inheritance, but I can't seem to grasp why this gives me an error (using Python 2.7.x).

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print 'First %s' % value

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print 'Second %s' % value

class Log(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        A.__init__(self, a)
        B.__init__(self, b)

        print 'Log'




x = Log(1000, 2222)



// Error: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 21, in <module>
#   File "<maya console>", line 13, in __init__
#   File "<maya console>", line 3, in __init__
# TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) //
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Preface:** my attempt to explain the MRO here is pretty deficient.  If you have 45 minutes, [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) by Raymond Hettinger from PyCon 2015 does a ***much*** better job.  Specifically, the idea of traversing "siblings", may be misleading.  Instead, the `super` calls simply follow the MRO, (see `help(Log)`).

Despite the downvotes, this is actually a good question.

Consider the slightly modified code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print 'A got: %s' % value

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print 'B got: %s' % value

class Log(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        A.__init__(self, a)
        B.__init__(self, b)

        print 'Log'
```

We can create instances of A and B without issue:

```
a = A("aa")  # A got: aa
b = B("bb")  # B got: bb
```

But when we try to create an instance of Log, we get an exception:

```
c = Log(123,456)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp2.py", line 21, in 
    c = Log(123, 456)
  File "temp2.py", line 13, in __init__
    A.__init__(self, a)
  File "temp2.py", line 3, in __init__
    super(A, self).__init__()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

To try to figure out what's going on here, we can give a default to the `value` parameters (I use `None`):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print 'A got: %s' % value

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print 'B got: %s' % value

class Log(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        A.__init__(self, a)
        B.__init__(self, b)

        print 'Log'
```

Now our same code runs without error:

```
c = Log(123, 456)
```

```
B got: None
A got: 123
B got: 456
Log
```

But the output might confuse you:  *Why were 2 B instances created?*  or *Why did specifying parameter defaults matter?*

Well, consider the following (again, slightly modified) code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        print 'A got: %s' % value
        super(A, self).__init__()

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        print 'B got: %s' % value
        super(B, self).__init__()

class Log(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        print("Before A")
        A.__init__(self, a)
        print("Before B")
        B.__init__(self, b)

        print 'Log'
```

Now, when we try to create our `c` object:

```
c = Log(123, 456)
```

We get:

```
Before A
A got: 123
B got: None
Before B
B got: 456
Log
```

What's happening here is that `super(A, self).__init__()` is actually calling `B.__init__()`.

This is because `super()` will traverse siblings before the parent looking for someone to implement the method.

In this case, it find's B's `__init__` method.  B's `__init__` method *then* also looks for siblings then parents, but since there are no siblings for B (as defined by the `Log` class -- which `self` is an instance of), B's `__init__` calls `object.__init__` which effectively does nothing.

Put another way (`init` being shorthand for `__init__`):

```
Log.init()
    A.init()
        super(A, self).init()      -->  B.init()
            super(B, self).init()  -->  object.init()
    B.init()
        super(B, self).init()      -->  object.init()
```

The reason the `super` inside `A.init()` finds `B.init()` (and not `object.init()` is because siblings are searched first.  And in the context of `self` (`Log(A,B)`), `B` will be checked first, before the parent class.

This won't go the other direction as you might notice, so the `super` inside `B.init()` *won't* find `A.init()`, and instead finds `object.init()`.  Again, this is because in the context of `Log`, `B` will be checked *after* `A`, followed by the parent class, `object`.

Some reading:

- [`super()` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)
- [Python's super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)
- [Python 2.3 Method Resolution Order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)

---

**EDIT:** To fix this, you could call the superclass `__init__` explicitly, instead of relying on `super()`:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        object.__init__(self)
        print 'First %s' % value

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        object.__init__(self)
        print 'Second %s' % value

class Log(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        A.__init__(self, a)
        B.__init__(self, b)

        print 'Log'

x = Log(1000, 2222)
```

Or, since `object.__init__()` effectively does nothing, you're able to simply re-write your code as:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        print 'First %s' % value

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        print 'Second %s' % value

class Log(A, B):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        A.__init__(self, a)
        B.__init__(self, b)

        print 'Log'

x = Log(1000, 2222)
```

Both of which will output what (I think) you expected:

```
First 1000
Second 2222
Log
```

Comment: Great explanation ! Thank you

Comment: I wish I found this much sooner! Thanks for the clear and simple explanation.